# Applet automatically closes sometime

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java-7

I have extremely strange thing going on with my java application. In summary, the problem is that it sometimes closes itself after 30-60 seconds of work.

The specifics of the situation are as follows:

- The application is actually launched in applet setting, the applet loads the main application jar, saves it to disk, then launches the actual program via reflection. The applet jar is signed, the application jar is not signed, so I had to override  the security manager. The code is as follows:

  ```
  System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager() {
     @Override public void checkPermission(Permission p) {}
  });
  URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] {mainJarFile.toURI().toURL()}, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
  Class<?> app = Class.forName("launch.App", true, loader);
  Method start = app.getDeclaredMethod("start", URL.class, URL.class);
  start.invoke(app.newInstance(), codeBase, documentBase);
  ```
- The crash happens only when the applet is run via `Citrix` connection to terminal servers.
- The crash isn't, in fact, a crash. In log file, I see that shutdown hooks are started and finished as they should during normal shutdown.
- If the applet is ran with java console visible and `trace` option on, I see the following message just before the shutdown:

  ```
  security: JSS is not configured
  network: Connecting https://javadl-esd-secure.oracle.com/update/baseline.version with proxy=HTTP @ FWR200/192.168.0.246:8080
  ```
- After the shutdown hook is started, the application seems to be still running, and I see exceptions like these in the log:

  ```
  2012.11.13 16:20:07.171 | def.pR.run:1639 | class java.lang.NullPointerException : null
      sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
      java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
      sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.findClassHelper(Unknown Source)
      sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)        
      ... // so on, the exception seems to happen in completely regular app code
  ```
- And finally, there was no such problem until those Citrix servers started using `Java 7` (specifically, java 7 update 9) instead of `Java 6`. Downgrading java doesn't seem to be an option.

I'm completely lost here. Can somebody at least give me some pointers about solving this problem? What could be the cause? Is there a way to work around these issues?

Comment: *"What could be the cause?"* It might be a bug in the JRE.  Check the [bug database](http://bugs.sun.com/), and if you don't find anything relevant, raise one.

Comment: @AndrewThompson - for which keywords should I look in that database?

Comment: The JRE version number might be a give-away.  I'd also throw in `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I hope you are authenticating the downloaded application properly before running it (by downloading it over SSL or by verifying it using a digitial signature in which case you might as well sign the jar).

To the problem. It could easily be because youre are running in the applet JVM. The lifecycle of the applet jvm is determined by the browser. So, if you still want to use an applet as the launcher then insert some debugging output in the `Applet.destroy()`, `Applet.stop()` methods of your applet subclass and see if that is related to the shutdown.

Another solution could be to launch it using Java Webstart. It really is the best way to launch java applications from the web.

Comment: I went with launching it via Java Webstart. Even if it fails at first, I would be able to rig it with a lot of jvm options and stuff, and finally close in on the problem. Also, JWS gives a *lot* more flexibility in general.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the security manager: doesn't that mean that you in fact **sidestep the whole Java applet security concept**? Publishing an applet that disables the security manager, then loads another application sounds like a **really bad idea** to me, in particular if you don't have about as much security checks in place as Java applets do. If anyone manages to grab this applet, they can probably use it to load exploit code from their own web site, and you might get your certificates revoked.

Around Java 7u7 a major security issue was fixed:

- http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/636312

But it wasn't yet completely fixed in 7u7:

- http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2012/Sep/170

And in fact, there is another one not yet fixed:

- http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2012/Oct/155

Maybe one of these changes affects your security-manager-side-stepping?